# Intellij 2020.1 shortcut to show VCS changes (modal commit dialogue)

Tags: git, intellij-idea

In the past I could hit CMD-9 on Mac to see my git changes.

Now IntelliJ now has a [modal commit dialogue](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/#version-control), so I don't see my changes in the git window which appears with CMD-9 anymore. Is there an existing keyboard shortcut to open the modal commit dialogue, or to see my git changes? (I know that I can revert to the old behaviour in settings, but I don't want this).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the 'Use non-modal commit interface' option is enabled under **File | Settings | Version Control | Commit**, `Alt+9` will open the Git tool window with the log, and `Ctrl+K` will open the Commit tool window with 'Local Changes' and 'Shelf' tabs.

[image]

If the option is disabled, 'Local Changes' tab moves to the Git tool window, and Commit window becomes modal.

Comment: The short answer to my question is: Ctrl-K. Thanks!